# Regex needs to match all zeros and double zeros between delimeters

Tags: java, regex, split, delimiter

So I need some help with regex. I have a code of numbers 1-26 with single zeros "0" representing a space and double zeros "00" representing a period, with a hyphen being used as a delimiter.

EX) 7-19-00-20-2-0

**I am trying to single out the single 0's (the double zeros will already be out of the equation**, without matching with the 20 and without snagging any hyphens either. I am writing in Java, this regex is to be used in a split command against a string.

Ex) "7-19-20-2-0".split([]);

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

### EDIT

I have tried various regex's that I would not be able to replicate, but the last one got me close. This was "[^0-9]0" which would only match the single 0's not preceded by a digit. The only problem with this was it would also match with the hyphen in front of the single zero. I couldn't figure out how to not include the character in front of the desired match.

## Final Edit

To clarify my ill-worded question, here is an example of expected input and output through a split command

```
"0-7-19-20-2-0-20-0".split(...) --> ["-7-19-20-2-", "-20-"]
```

Notice only the single zeros were split, leaving the hyphen delimiters where they stand

Comment: I have tried various regex that I would not be able to replicate, but the last one got me close. This was "[^0-9]0" which would only match the single 0's not preceded by a digit. The only problem with this was it would also match with the hyphen in front of the single zero. I coudn't figure out how to not include the character in front of the desired match.

Comment: Don't post clarifications in a comment. **Edit** the question to clarify it. Delete the comment.

Comment: chill. I was responding to someone who apparently deleted their comment.

Comment: Given the input `7-19-00-20-2-0`, what exactly is the expected output?

Comment: Good question Tim, I will add that to my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `-` dash-delimited string, to match single 0's you need to use look-around's.

The `0` must be at beginning of string (`^`) or preceded by a `-` dash, *and* must be at end of string (`$`) or followed by a `-` dash.

```regex
(?<=^|-)0(?=-|$)
```

Comment: Not the most efficient way to write that regex.  You can avoid alternations in the lookarounds.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How?

Comment: Try `(?<![^-])0(?![^-])` ... but I'm not even certain this is what the OP actually wants here.

Comment: That is it! The look-around is what I could not figure out

Comment: Then accept this answer +1, and next time you post here please clearly tell us the outcome you want.